# Realloc array of pointers to an Struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, realloc

I have an struct like that:

```
struct _Total {
    Socio *socio[0];
    Libro *libro[0];
    int numsocios;
    int numlibros;
};
```

I have a practice in my university and I need to realloc "socio" and "libro" pointer each time I add data. For example, if a have only one "socio" the array need to be of size 1, if I add another "socio" I need to realloc it to size 2 and then add the pointer to the new struct (the counter is "numsocios"). Same for "libro".

I tried this function (in total.c file) but obviously I'm having type error:

```
STATUS total_ajustarsocio(Socio **socio, int tam) {

    Socio *temp = NULL;

    if (!socio) {
        return ERROR;
    }

    temp = (Socio *) realloc (*socio, tam * sizeof(Socio));

    if (!temp) {
        printf("Error reallocating Socio");
        return ERROR;
    }

    *socio = temp;

    return OK;
}
```

So, how can I solve mi problem?

P.S. This is the Socio struct (in socio.c - it has function to malloc and free in this file, too).

```
struct _Socio {
    char nombre[MAXCAR];
    char apellido[MAXCAR];
    int dni;
    char direccion[MAXCAR];
    int tlf;
    int numprestamos;
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: I do not see any problem. Why do you think you have one?

Comment: Do you also have `typedef struct _Socio Socio;`?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Also don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, I have this in socio.h file

Comment: @Michael total.c: In function ‘total_ajustarsocio’:
total.c:186:52: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘Socio’
     temp = (Socio *) realloc (*socio, tam * sizeof(Socio));
                                                    ^
make: *** [total.o] Error 1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8915230/669576

Comment: @Olaf I only need to realloc anything more. I explain something about why I need to use that, but the problem is only to realloc the array to be able to do that

Comment: @Marta Your `typedef struct _Socio Socio;` declaration does not appear before the declaration of `total_ajustarsocio()`. Please check your code

Comment: Socio *libro [0]" looks very, very, very suspicious to me.

Comment: Global identifiers starting with underscores are really convenient for hiding implementation details. Unfortunately,  the standard committee thinks so too and reserved them all. Don't use names starting with an underscore for your types or functions, or you may find yourself with strange build issues .

Comment: @Michael The include to socio.h is in total.h file before the declaration of function

Comment: @gnasher729 "Socio *libro[0]" is like "Socio *libro[]"

Comment: @Maria Please try replacing `Socio` with `struct _Socio` inside `realloc (*socio, tam * sizeof(Socio))`

Comment: @Michael total.c:186:42: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct _Socio’

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I have something like that, for each space of array is there a  malloc of the struct.

total->socio[0] = socio_ini();
total->socio[1] = socio_ini();

etc...

the problem is thet I can't increase the array from the initial value (the example is with 0 as size but other value is valid... only need to increase the initial value of array of pointers to Socio)

Comment: @Marta It seems that you only completely define `struct _Socio` in "socio.c", so it is not surprising that you are getting `sizeof` errors in "total.c". You need to move the complete declaration of `Struct _Socio` into "socio.h" so that "total.c" can see it. Alternatively, you could move all the functions that need to know the size of `struct _Socio` into "socio.c".

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, solved now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `struct _Total` is wrong. It should be:

```
struct _Total {
    Socio *socio;
    Libro *libro;
    int numsocios;
    int numlibros;
};
```

Your `total_ajustarsocio` function might be called something like this:

```
total.numsocios++;
err = total_ajustarsocio(&total.socio, total.numsocios);
```

Comment: I edited my answer after 2 up votes, as I don't think my original answer matched what OP was trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks, I test it yesterday but I can't access to array with this implementation.

total.c:40:36: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
         destruir_socio(total->socio[i]);

Comment: Into `struct _Total`: `Socio *socio;` should be `struct Socio *socio;` The same for `libro`.

Comment: Same problem of dereferencing:

total.c:40:9: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct Socio’
         destruir_socio(total->socio[i]);
         ^
total.c:40:36: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
         destruir_socio(total->socio[i]);

Comment: @MartaGarcia How is `Socio.h` included in [tag:c] source file? Where is `struct _Total` declared?

Comment: @LPs, I'm assuming there is a `typedef struct _Socio Socio` and a `typedef struct _Libro Libro` before the declaration of `struct _Total`. (Marta mentioned that `Socio` was declared with a `typedef`, so I assume `Libro` is also declared.)

Comment: @IanAbbott I know but the evidence is that is not, or the file where `struct _Total` is declared has no visibility of `Socio` `typedef` or `struct`

Comment: @LPs I guess the compiler would have produced errors when compiling the complete declaration of `struct _Total` if the types `Socio` and `Libro` were not at least partially defined at that point. But yes, we need more information from Marta about the order in which various declarations occur in the code.

Comment: Total.h file:

#include "socio.h"
#include "libro.h"

And for example socio.h file:

#ifndef SOCIO_H
#define SOCIO_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "types.h"

#define MAXCAR 100

typedef struct _Socio Socio;

FUNCTIONS

#endif

Comment: And Makefile have all dependecies

Comment: @MartaGarcia Well the problem is the visibility of `struct _Socio`. Move it into `Socio.h`, where it should naturally be placed, before `typedef`.

Comment: @MartaGarcia I have no idea what your `destruir_socio` function is supposed to do since it isn't included in your question.

Comment: @LPs Thank you! Yes, this is the solution. It's because of hidding implantation, but I don't need to hide this, so now is solved.

Comment: @IanAbbott Don't worry, this function it's to make "free" but worked perfect. This call is in a loop to free all array. Now it solved moving definition of structures to header file.

Comment: @MartaGarcia By "This call is in a loop to free all array", I hope you don't mean you are allocating a dynamic array with `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` and then trying to free each element individually with `free`, because that won't work.

Comment: @MartaGarcia Good. just a side note. If you want to hide struct members you should implement a bunch of `get`/`set` functions and code outside of module cannot refer to the variable, that should be something like `typedef void * my_hide_struct`, directly. [tag:c++] private like.

Comment: @IanAbbott It is only to free before exiting the program. Thanks!